# R - get z-score equivalents

Tags: r

Assume we have a following numeric vector in R, whose values can range from 1 to 5:

```
vec <- c(4.6, 1.2, 3.5, 2.1, 3, 1.1, 4.6)
```

It would be pretty easy to calculate z-scores on this vector:

```
scale(vec)


            [,1]
[1,]  1.17822372
[2,] -1.13927417
[3,]  0.42844499
[4,] -0.52581885
[5,]  0.08763647
[6,] -1.20743587
[7,]  1.17822372
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 2.871429
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 1.4671
```

However, what I want is a data frame with two columns. The first column shows the integer values which `vec` can take, and the second column show what would be the equivalent z-scores, given the observed data.

I just don't know how to construct the second column. If the data happens to contain integer numbers, such as in my example, it's easy to find that if `vec = 3`, `vec_z = 0.08763647`. However, these actual integers are rarely found in the data that I am dealing with. So what would be the fastest way to construct this?

**EDIT**

For some reason, I already got two answers, which just suggested that I merge `vec` and `vec_z` into a data frame. Both authors deleted their answers. This is not what I am asking - please, pay attention to the part of my question where I say that I need ***integers*** in the first column. So given that I have `vec`, how do I make a dataframe like this:

```
A B
1 
2
3
4
5
```

Where the values in `B` would be corresponding z-values which could be calculated given the observed data in `vec`.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here around what "z-scores" are. `scale` simply transforms data `x` according `z = (x - mean(x) / sd(x)`. So a value of z = 3 means that the corresponding `x` is 3 standard deviations away from the mean. Obviously this depends on your values for `x`. So it is incorrect to say "it's easy to find that if vec = 3, vec_z = 0.08763647" as this will depend on your data for `x` (try for yourself by first replacing a value with, and then adding a value of 3 to your original `vec` and observe how the scaled version is different). What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I know that it will be different depending on the data, as this is entry-level statistics knowledge. You could also see that from the part of my question where I say "given the observed data". So I am not sure what you are trying to ask me from your comment.

Comment: No need to get upset. I'm just trying to understand what you're asking. So are you simply after `data.frame(x = 1:5, z = scale(1:5))`?

Comment: No. I am in a situation where I have values from vec as described in the question, and I want to calculate what would be the corresponding z-values of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 given the observed data which exists in vec.

Comment: Or `some_two_col <- data.frame(Int = round(vec), z= scale(vec))` perhaps, though otherwise I fail to understand.

Comment: @Chris Let's say that you have these following numbers: 1, 2, 3 in a vector named bla. The corresponding z-values are -1, 0 and 1. What would be the corresponding z-value of 4, without adding 4 to the vector bla? It would be 2. Right? Imagine that instead of just one number, 4, I want to do this for several numbers - 4, 5, 6, and 7. Let's call this vector blabla.

So what I want is a dataframe where the first column contains blabla and the second column contains corresponding z-scores, calculated not on the scale of blabla, but on the scale of bla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for.

Starting with your vector:

```
vec <- c(4.6, 1.2, 3.5, 2.1, 3, 1.1, 4.6)
```

You can use `scale` and it will provide the mean and SD stored as attributes:

```
s <- scale(vec)
attributes(s)

$dim
[1] 7 1

$`scaled:center`
[1] 2.871429

$`scaled:scale`
[1] 1.4671
```

Then you can use those attributes to scale whatever new integers you want to include in your final data.frame.

```
my_int <- 1:10

data.frame(
  int = my_int,
  scaled_val = (my_int - attr(s, "scaled:center")) / attr(s, "scaled:scale")
)
```

**Output**

```
   int  scaled_val
1    1 -1.27559758
2    2 -0.59398055
3    3  0.08763647
4    4  0.76925350
5    5  1.45087053
6    6  2.13248755
7    7  2.81410458
8    8  3.49572160
9    9  4.17733863
10  10  4.85895566
```